# Basic Authentication in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, basic-authentication

I'm trying to connect to a third party vendor that requires a basic authentication. I basically need to download html/js/css and view the content on my website. I can already connect to the site using the code below. The problem is that the content below references js and css that are relative to the other domain and also require basic authentication themselves. I have tried setting the 'resolveUrl' to true which seems like the right step, but I cannot get passed the basic authentication block. I appreciate all the help I can get on this.

```
<cfscript>
    httpService = new http();

    httpService.setURL("https://example.com");
    httpService.setMethod("GET");
    httpService.setUsername("someusername");
    httpService.setPassword("somepassword");
    httpService.setResolveUrl(true);

    prefix = httpService.send().getPrefix();
    fileContent = prefix.fileContent;

    writeOutput(fileContent);
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is ResolveURL doing as expected? What is your intent? Would you like to gather urls from the document so that you know where to collect from?

There are many many topics on converting links within a text to hyperlinks. You could easily adapt that and collect an array using `ReMatch()`.

You could even use Adobe's example:

```
result = REMatch("https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?", cfhttp.filecontent);
```

I haven't tested this but, but I feel like this change might work

```
result = REMatch("https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\.js|\.css.|\.other|\.ext|\.you|\.wnt|\.hre)(\?\S+)?)?)?", cfhttp.filecontent);
```

Or something simple like

```
result = REMatch("http[s]?://([^\s"">])*(\.js|\.css.|\.other|\.ext|\.you|\.wnt|\.hre)([^\s"">])*", cfhttp.filecontent);
```

You have to prefix the `.` in extensions with a `\` because `.` is a special character in regex (it's a wildcard meaning any character)

Result returns an array of every match within the request. You could play with it so that it only filters to files ending in certain extensions.

After getting the results array, I'd do some crunching to make sure that I didn't have any duplicate urls and then cfloop over the array and dl the content.

A rudimentary spider :).